# Concrete screws not going in all the way

Tags: concrete, screws, anchor

I'm attempting to use tapcon 1/4in by 2.75in concrete screws to affix something to a wall of poured concrete, but it's only going about 3/5 of the way in before refusing to go any further. I used the recommended tapcon drill bit size so I don't think that's the issue, and I've also air blasted all the dust out. What else could it be? Do I just need a more powerful drill? A smaller size screw?

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b9Y14.jpg

Comment: Are you sure you have drilled the pilot hole deep enough?  Check it with something that will fit and be sure it's as deep as it should be.

Comment: How deep does it need to be? It's slightly longer than the length of the screw.

Comment: The Tapcons that I have used list the required pilot hole size and depth on the package.

Comment: What kind of drill are you using to drive the screw? (It might just be underpowered.) You might also try reversing a bit as you stall out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's far too long a screw for that application. 2-3/4" screws are designed for mounting 2x4 lumber, for example, which would leave just 1-1/4" of penetration or so.

Concrete screws, especially thinner ones like that, should only engage the concrete maybe an inch or a bit more. If you try running that in with a stronger drill it'll almost certainly snap.

Try the 1-1/4" screws, and be aware that running them in more than once usually results in the threaded concrete failing due to the grinding effect of insertion. They should be a once-and-done install. Move to a new hole if that one doesn't seem to hold with a shorter screw, or use some epoxy to rebuild the bond.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing and it worked great!